# XAML Load Image into Grid

Tags: image, xaml, uwp, insert, grid

I am new to UWP and try to learn a few basics, but i am currently struggling.
I have a button "To-Do" and want to Display a Image of a to-do-list above the button.
So i try this.. but that doesnt show me the Image. What did i wrong?
Thank you for your help!!!

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,60,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/Bilder/todo.png" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.RowSpan="8" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btnNaviZuToDo" Content="To-Do Liste" Height="86" Width="250" FontSize="40" Click="Button_NavigiereZuToDo" Margin="0,0,-2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri Light"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hello, please check your image path is correct. Usually we will use `ms-appx:///` as a prefix to define the root directory of the project. If the picture is in the `Assets` folder (which in the root of project), you can write: `ms-appx:///Assets/todo.png`, you can adjust your picture path accordingly.

Comment: it is working!! thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your image path is correct.

Usually we will use `ms-appx:///` as a prefix to define the root directory of the project. If the picture is in the **Assets** folder (which in the root of project), you can write: `ms-appx:///Assets/todo.png`, you can adjust your picture path accordingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `todo.png`'s build action to `Content`.

[image]